# SSRS - weekday sort in graph

Tags: sorting, reporting-services, graph

I have a graph that compares transactions from the last 7 days (including the current day), to the 7 days before that.

However, I've noticed that sometimes during the day, the order of the days is incorrect.
When I open the report again it is the correct, without me doing anything to fix it.

[image]

The above graph was created on Sunday morning, and the Saturday and Friday values are switched around. Since it's Sunday morning, the graph should start on Monday, and end on Sunday.

Later on, it displayed as it should.

The data is as follows (unfortunately I could only pull data as it was when the graph was shown correctly.) There are 2 products that are grouped together in the graph.

```
Brand   Date    DepositAmount   DayOfWeek   WeekSeries
B       10/02/2014  1630        Monday      Previous Week
A       11/02/2014  13717       Tuesday     Previous Week
B       12/02/2014  2460        Wednesday   Previous Week
A       13/02/2014  4941        Thursday    Previous Week
A       18/02/2014  9194        Tuesday     Current Week
B       19/02/2014  1947        Wednesday   Current Week
A       20/02/2014  4185        Thursday    Current Week
B       21/02/2014   273        Friday      Current Week
A       22/02/2014  2521        Saturday    Current Week
B       22/02/2014  1118        Saturday    Current Week
A       23/02/2014  1438        Sunday      Current Week
B       23/02/2014   105        Sunday      Current Week
A       14/02/2014  4958        Friday      Previous Week
B       14/02/2014  1023        Friday      Previous Week
A       15/02/2014  2465        Saturday    Previous Week
B       15/02/2014  1208        Saturday    Previous Week
A       16/02/2014  3495        Sunday      Previous Week
B       16/02/2014   680        Sunday      Previous Week
A       17/02/2014  2726        Monday      Current Week
B       17/02/2014  1177        Monday      Current Week
A       10/02/2014  4938        Monday      Previous Week
B       11/02/2014  1543        Tuesday     Previous Week
A       12/02/2014  7891        Wednesday   Previous Week
B       13/02/2014  5490        Thursday    Previous Week
B       18/02/2014  4726        Tuesday     Current Week
A       19/02/2014  9009        Wednesday   Current Week
B       20/02/2014   459        Thursday    Current Week
A       21/02/2014  6012        Friday      Current Week
```

In SSRS, the graph is defined as follows:

Category Groups: DayOfWeek (sorted by Date (A to z))

Series Groups: WeekSeries (sorted by WeekSeries (A to Z)).

Any ideas what may be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is in your Category Group sort - you are Grouping by DayOfWeek but then sorting by Date which has multiple values. The first row for Friday could get the Current Week Date or the Previous Week Date at random.

To fix this, for the Category Group sort, I would derive a "Relative DayOfWeek" value, something like:

= Abs ( DateDiff ( DateInterval.Day , Today() , Iif ( Fields!WeekSeries.Value = "Current Week" , Fields!Date.Value, DateAdd ( DateInterval.Day , 7 , Fields!Date.Value ) ) )

Comment: Thank you @Mike. I've implemented, and it seems to work. (Just to clarify, the formula calculates the number of days from the data day to today, so from 7 down to 1, so you also have to change the sort order to 'Z to A'.)